# Is there any specific trading strategy for ETH?

Tags: ether

Does anyone have developed and tested an Ethereum trading strategy and it the tests have given good results?

I know there are some examples for Bitcoin for example but I don't know if anyone has yet done it with Ether

Comment: Hi, I see [multiple issues with this question](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). A) It's 4 questions. B) It tends to be primarily opinion based and C) It's unclear what you are asking here, especially 2 - what is tested, 3 - a bot for which strategy? Please, [ask one question per thread and add as many details to your problem statement](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as possible.

Comment: I've edited the question with one specific question

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not getting your question. Please try not only to clarify your question but also show some research effords or add some examples about what you are trying to do. Is this a technical question?

Comment: Not at all, there are some people who developed some strategies for buying/selling Bitcoin in some specific conditions, I just want to know if there is some strategy like that with Ether

Answer (score 1):

I think for the moment, best strategy is buy (or mine) and keep it safe ;)